# Why did php5-fpm restart fail?

Tags: php, php-fpm

I am getting this error when I restart PHP:

> Restarting PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager: php5-fpm failed!

I am now phpless. I did touch the config file, but I can’t undo it as I lost my connection and I did not back it up.

Here is my current `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` with all the comment lines removed.

```
[www]
listen = /var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fcgi.socket
user = php-www
group = php-www
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5

chdir = /
```

What’s wrong with that? And what log file can I look into to find the reason it failed?

Comment: Which distro? Specify a `error_log` directive in the `php-fpm.conf`, under `[global]` section, try again and take a look at this.

Comment: I temporarily fixed it by copying/pasting a copy i found on the internet. I'll be away for the rest of today. -edit- debian squeeze

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when there's another process running that was spawned from php-fpm. For example, I have a page that runs ImageMagick from command line in order to create thumbnails from images. If I try to restart php-fpm while ImageMagick is still running then it will fail after a timeout of it waiting for the process to finish.

Comment: Thanks! My php still seems to run and wordpress is working, even after a restart fail. So do I need to something now with `killall` or can I just leave it be?

Comment: Okay, I did `service php5-fpm stop` and started again and that worked.